# How-to: Simple GitPod Environment for Php and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, gitpod

Simple: I want to use an online environment to work on some simple PhP  coding. Such that I can work from anywhere with my work computers (no admin rights) and maybe even with an iPad.

I though it should be quite straightforward to set this up on GitPod. However, all is somewhat very complex for a beginner like me. I am sure its all not that complicated, I am just a little lost. Thanks for help! Any blog articles or step by step guide greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just PHP:

- https://github.com/gitpod-io/apache-example

Including XDebug:

- https://github.com/Eetezadi/Gitpod-Apache-PHP-Xdebug

Wordpress Developing Environment:

- https://github.com/Eetezadi/Gitpod-Wordpress-Development